# Injecting commands into Command Line based Process

Tags: c#-4.0

Currently I am working on a server manager. The server is a command line application. The server is ran through the Process class, and the window is hidden. I've been trying to figure out a way to inject commands into it (save-all), without showing the server window. I have tried to use StreamWriter and the Process's Standard Input, but that didn't work. Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: How it doesn't work? show as the relevant code you tried so far to start the process and use its `StandardInput`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to redirect any of the standard I/O streams of a process, you need to disable shell execute.  You probably didn't.  You should be able to do it like this:

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMSPEC"),
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
    },
};
if (process.Start())
{
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo FOOBAR!");
    process.WaitForExit(3000);
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```